# Error when removing white spaces with trim functions C++

Tags: c++

I have a cpp file that grabs lines and trims them but i'm getting an error.

The error says:

`error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'`

I'm not sure what it means... but this is the script...:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include "settings.h"

using namespace std;

// trim from start
static inline std::string& line_trim(std::string& s) {

    //erase 
    s.erase(
            //pointer start location
            s.begin(),

            //find from pointer which is set to begin
                std::find_if( s.begin(), 
            //check to the end
                s.end(), 
            //look for spaces
                std::not1( std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace) ) ) );

    //return the result
        return s;
}

// trim from end
static inline std::string& end_trim(std::string& s) {

    //erase   
    s.erase(

            //find from the pointer set to end of line
                std::find_if(s.rbegin(),

            //check to the beginning (because were starting from end of line
                s.rend(), 

            //look for spaces
                std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))).base(),
                s.end());
        return s;
}


static inline std::string& trim(std::string &s) {
    return line_trim(end_trim(s));
}

ifstream file(std::string file_path){
string line;

    std::map<string, string> config;

    while(std::getline(file, line))
    {
        int pos = line.find('=');
        if(pos != string::npos)
        {
            string key = line.substr(0, pos);
            string value = line.substr(pos + 1);
            config[trim(key)] = trim(value);
        }
    }
    return (config);
}
```

The error is occuring in the 3rd function on this like:

`while(std::getline(file, line))`

EDIT: This is my `settings.h`

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

static inline std::string &line_trim(std::string&);

static inline std::string &end_trim(std::string&);

static inline std::string &trim(std::string&);

std::map<string, string> loadSettings(std::string);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Sarang see edit - i have added it at the bottom :)

Comment: I am really confused by the end of your first code block... where is the function header that returns an `std::map<string, string>`?

Comment: You mean this `return (config);` ?

Comment: You've named a function `file`, and included a lot of irrelevant code in your question.

Comment: @Dave Not quite the return, but the function declaration for the block that's returning... see Sarang's answer.

Comment: One more point that's generally quite helpful is an indication of what part of the code the error message points to (it originally included a line number...)

Comment: Under main block of code i highlighted the line before the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm piecing two and two together based on your `settings.h` file... I think you've forgotten to write out your function header.  This bit:

```
ifstream file(std::string file_path){
string line;

    std::map<string, string> config;
```

should be:

```
std::map<string, string> loadSettings(std::string file_path) {
    ifstream file(file_path);
    string line;
    std::map<string, string> config;
```

With your current implementation, `file` is a function (because it has scope from the opening `{`), so it is not the expected argument to `getline`.

Comment: Ah that seems to have fixed the error - although it produced `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'std::string &'` Does it mean i have to make a copy and cannot use reference?

Comment: You should be able to fix that by passing std::string("Settings.txt") or declaring a variable `std::string s("Settings.txt")` and passing `s`.  One of those will work.

Comment: So this is now incorrect `std::map<string, string> config = loadSettings("Settings.txt");` ?

Comment: Not quite, C++ just isn't sure how to implicitly convert from a `const char` array (`"Settings.txt"`) to an std::string.  You have to help it out a bit.

Comment: Ah i removed the `&` from the string and that seemed to solve it. Seems i have to make a copy for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the var file?

```
ifstream file(std::string file_path){
string line;

    std::map<string, string> config;

    while(std::getline(file, line))
```

In here file is function, and getline expects basic_istream
thus the failure

Comment: Well main.cpp has `std::map<string, string> config = loadSettings("Settings.txt");` but how do i connect this to the file function ?

Comment: This isn't right. function name file is conflicting with parameter name - getline(file,line)